# Contextmenu and Picturebox c++

Tags: c++, winforms, clr

I created a program like Paint and ran into this problem: I have a PictureBox where I can draw, but I want to be able to copy and paste part of the image from my PictureBox. Created Contextmenu, but I can not properly describe the copy and paste commands. I work in C ++ and want to know if it is possible to do such an action? 
If possible, give an example of a simple copy and paste image code.

Comment: Do you have any code example, where you've working on? Please consider to take a look at [how to provide a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The fact is that I have the code of the program itself, but I can’t implement the code for copying and pasting the part of the image that I selected. If you can give a simple example of program code, I will be very grateful.

Comment: You could check this [markdown editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)